# gcc compiling error for c++ program

Tags: gcc, c++

When I'm trying to compile a C++ program with `gcc`, it gives me following error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `g++` package on your machine. Install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

[Reference](http://www.ducea.com/2007/10/25/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1plus-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory/).

Comment: Just for a clarification: Default Ubuntu installation comes with `gcc`, but not with `g++`.